# Iterating changes over multiple labels at once

Tags: java

I am trying to make a function in my program that will read a string, and then set every jlabel on my page to that string. I am aware of .setText(); but I am intending to do this to 100's of labels at once. Using the below code I intended to use a for loop and call the method for as many times as I will have labels and send the label name within the function. i.e.

```
button.pressed() {
    updateLabel(labelName);
}

public void updateLabel(String name) {
    …
}
```

But to test the code initially I just hardcoded the name of one label in and ran it. the first time it worked but now I get a null pointer exception every time. please someone help. The actual code below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   labeltest(); 
}                                        

public void labeltest() {

    for (Component c : this.getContentPane().getComponents()) {
        if (c.getName().equals("Jlabel")) {
            // do the modifications...
            ((JLabel) c).setText("Updated");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Component.name` is `null`, therefore to select only label, you should use `instance of`:

```
private void updateLabels(String str) {
    for (Component component : getContentPane().getComponents())
        if (component instanceof JLabel)
            ((JLabel)component).setText(str);
}
```

I think in general case, there're many component on the panel and a few labels. Therefore 
using `for (Component component : getComponents())  {}` is not the best solution.

In case you want to set the same text to all the labels, then is is better to create a `List<JLabel>` with all labels that should be updated and us it to set a text:

```
private final List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();

private void init() {
    add(createLabel());
}

// hide add to labels within create method
private JLabel createLabel() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel():
    labels.add(label);
    return label;
}
```

In case you want to set different text to the labels, then it is better to set correct name for the labels and use `Map<String, JLabel>` with all labels:

```
private final Map<String, JLabel> labels = new HashMap<>();
private final static String NAME_ACCOUNT = "account";
private final static String NAME_SCORE = "score";

private void int() {
    add(createLabel(NAME_ACCOUNT));
    add(createLabel(NAME_SCORE);
}

    // hide add to labels within create method
    private JLabel createLabel(String name) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel():
        label.setName(name);
        labels.put(name, label);
        return label;
    }
```

Comment: The original poster has apparently abandoned us, but regardless, I like your suggestions 1+

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential problem:

```
if (c.getName().equals("Jlabel")) {
```

as most Swing components don't have the name property set unless you, the coder, *explicitly* set it, and I have to wonder if this is the source of your NullPointerException.

Better to do:

```
if (c instanceof JLabel) {
    // ....
}
```

So yes, you could recursively iterate through all components held in all Containers on your GUI, checking each if `instanceof JLabel`, and then casting and setting, but ... no, this is not clean, not good.

Why not simply put the JLabels into a collection such as

```
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then use a for loop, iterate over the list and change the state of the labels.

.... or I wonder if you're looking to use other components to display your Strings, such as a `JList<String>` perhaps?

Comment: The Labels themselves all have custom icon backgrounds, I only want the text to change. Also, if I  can get the above code working, my end goal is to write different type to each label.

Comment: @Kyle: a JList can hold cells that each display its own Icon, so this could still work just fine, if the labels are held in a grid of some sort.

Comment: I originally looked at using a map and key for each label, but this has the same issue as before of having to directly address each label when wanting to set their properties. Also, new labels can be added whilst the programs running. How would it work with the new labels?